# Jquery is not validating my form

Tags: php, jquery

I want validate my form using jquery (the field 'name1' is required and 'email' is also required and should in email format. I followed the tutorials, but I couldn't get it work. How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
     <html>
        <head>
   <script src="/webvanta/js/jquery/1.4/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webvanta/js/jquery/1.4/plugins/form/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/webvanta/js/jquery/1.4/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#myform").validate({
           rules: {
             name1: "required",
             email: {
               required: true,
               email: true
             }
           },
           messages: {
             name1: "Please specify your name",
             email: {
               required: "We need your email address to contact you",
               email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
             }
           }
        })
        });

        </script>

        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

        <form id = "myform" action="picture.php" method="get">
        Picture name: <input name="name1" class="required"   /><br>
        Email: <input name="email" class="required"  />

        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
        </form>
        <br>




        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Consider using newer/latest version of jQuery. 1.4.2 is about 2.5 y old.

Comment: Actually it is not a notice, it is the reason why your code is not working. I just checked the code with latest jQuery and latest version of validation plugin - it works.

Comment: I would suggest you check the fields with php, not with js. Serialize the form, use ajax to send the data to a php file and let php validate it. Then you receive the answer of the php file with ajax again and can display the errors if there are some...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure to try code with the latest versions of the libraries you use. Old libraries and old plugins may contain lots of bugs and be not compliant.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple ajax example:

```
   $("#submit").click( function() { 

    var str = $("#your-form").serialize();


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url-to-your-file.php",
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {

          if(msg=="1") {//let's say 1 means error, do stuff here}
          if(success=="0){//success, do stuff here}
          }
    });


    });
```

In your php file check and validate the input. If it's OK, echo 0, else echo 1 - just as an example to keep it very simple here.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will consider using this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off: I've never used this function myself so I'm not sure if the method you've provided is valid. However, this is not the way it's described in the jQuery documentation. As @Tim suggested, first switch to the latest jQuery version, then go ahead and try as described in this documentation page:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#source

With this said, you still need to add server-side validation aswell, so I'd just go ahead and use ajax and server-side validation (from a php-file or similar) instead. Then you'll have identical methods for both server-side validation and client-side validation. If you're not using a database layer however, server-side validation might be to overdo it.